# How to make "list view" the default view in newly opened windows?

Tags: files, linux-mint, cinnamon

I am using Linux Mint 20.2 with Cinnamon desktop environment.

Is there a setting for the default view of the newly opened windows, in the  file browser?

I know that I can select list view with ctrl-2 keyboard shortcut, but since I use the list view most of the times, I would like to set that view as default.

I don't know if this would be a setting specific to Cinnamon, or it is something that works for several (all?) desktop environments and file browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you mean file browser instead of window manager?

Comment: hmm... I am not sure of the names here... what I mean is the "thing" that shows me the files in my disks :)

Comment: Yes, that's the file browser, window manager is another concept. In cinnamon it's called Nemo.

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Nemo (file manager)

- Edit/Preferences/Views

[image: nemo]

---

> I don't know if this would be a setting specific to Cinnamon, or it is something that works for several (all?) desktop environments and file browsers.

---

Files (also known as Nautilus) is the default file manager for GNOME. *Files is simple to configure graphically, but not all options are available in the preferences menu.*

Source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Files#Change_default_item_view

I've tested with Fedora 34 and Ubuntu 21.04 and didn't find how to change graphically the default view. I think in old versions of Nautilus it was possible, not sure now.

---

With Dolphin (a KDE file manager) you can do this graphically.

With Thunar (a Xfce file manager) it can be done graphically. You have to check the option *Remember view settings for each folder*. and select *View new folders using List View*.

Comment: It took me some minutes to understand that "Open Nemo" means "open a new window in the file browser"... :)
Thanks it works!

Answer (score 1):

So this is for caja (Mate) but assuming sinilar for you.

1. Open the file browser (this should be already in your panel, but you can also open from menu)
2. Go into Edit/Preferences/Views
3. Select 'list view' and this should iterate throughout your whole file system (including files outside home directory)

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Answering old questions is perfectly fine, but at this point another answer should give something previously not presented. Instead you're repeating the already-accepted answer, so what exactly is the new thing you're bringing to the table? As you're new here, I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), checking the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and reviewing some old questions with [accepted answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how the site works.